# How to find left and right subarray for each index which follows below mentioned criteria?

Tags: c

There is a sequence problem wherein for each index
**i** in the array we define two quantities.

Let **`r`** be the maximum index such that
**`r>=i`** and sub-array from **`i`** to **`r`** (inclusive) is either non-decreasing or non-increasing.

Let **`l`** be the minimum index such that **`l<=i`** and sub-array from **`l`** to **i** (inclusive) is either non-decreasing or non-increasing.

Now, we define points of an index **`i`** to be equal to

**`max(|Ai−Al|,|Ai−Ar|)`**.

Note that `l` and `r` can be different for each index.

The task of the problem is to find the index of the array `A` which have the maximum points.

**My Logic :**

1. First scan all the elements in the array .
2. For every index find l and r which either follows an increasing or decreasing sequence and then calculate the maximum point for that index.

My problem is that this is taking `O(N^2)` time.

**Can the problem be done in less time?**

Comment: what will happen if two number in the sequence have the same points

Comment: Except when `i` is the first element, `l` will be strictly less than `i`; similarly, except when `i` is the last element, `r` will be strictly greater than `i`.  I'm not sure if that helps at all.

Comment: @leyanpan , we have to print maximum so doesn't matter if two indexes have same points .

Comment: I tried  by considering the case when i is the first element for this element l=0 and otherwise I started from l=i-1 , but still my focus is on to reduce time complexity for this code

Comment: Please provide some sample input with desired result. Also please show what code you already have.

Comment: I was coding for this problem : Sample Input is provided in this link itself .My code passed on sample input but overall it is failing :                               https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/arrays/1-d/practice-problems/algorithm/zulu-encounters-a-sequence-problem/                            And here is my code link :                                                                                    https://ideone.com/QT0kix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two consecutive identical number have the same point and does not affect the point of any other point, so it is possible to assume that this scenario does not exist.

So consider a input array a which has no consecutive identical numbers, it can be assumed that the longest none-decreasing or none-increasing in sub sequence are [`0`, `I1`] [`I1`, `I2`] ... [`Ix`, `n - 1`], which is denoted by index and n is the length of the array. Each decreasing sub sequence is followed by a increasing sub sequence and vice versa.

For any Ii, the point with index Ii have point equal to `max(|AIi - AI(i - 1)|, |AIi - AI(i + 1)|)`. Any index between `Ii` and `I(i + 1)` have point less than `Ii` and `I(i + 1)` and do not have to be considered.

So we only need to find out the maximum value between all `AIi` and`AI(i + 1)` .

After a huge lot of attempts, I finally got my program accepted (mainly because the difference between two int 32 are not necessarily in the range of a signed int 32 range), and the code is as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXN 200002
long long a[MAXN];

long long abs(long long n)
{
    if (n >= 0)
        return n;
    return -n;
}

long long find_score(int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    long long maximum_score = 0;
    while (i < size - 1)
    {
        //Jump over consecutive indentical numbers
        while (a[i + 1] == a[i])
        {
            if (i < size - 1)
                i++;
            else
                break;
        }
        int j = i + 1;
        int inc_or_dec = a[j] > a[i];
        while (j < size - 1 && (!((a[j + 1] > a[j]) ^ inc_or_dec) || a[j + 1] == a[j]))j++;
        if (abs(a[j] - a[i]) > maximum_score)
            maximum_score = abs(a[j] - a[i]);
        i = j;
    }
    return maximum_score;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (n--)
    {
        int num;
        scanf("%d", &num);
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            scanf("%lld", a + i);
        }
        printf("%lld\n", find_score(num));
    }
    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

Glad to know if there are any "implementation defined" problems in my code.